# Currency app needs update

Tags: java, android, logcat, crash

I just need som minor help now. The app runs great but when you enter for ex. USD, 2 TO SEK it results 13,38. But if i change the amount to 3 nothing happens. I would have to change the currencys back and forth to make a change. I would like the app to change the result as soon as i change the value. Please help!:)

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 private String [] currency_name;
 private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 private Spinner spin1, spin2;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



 setUpTheSpinners();



 }
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        return true;
    }


 private void setUpTheSpinners() {
 currency_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_name);
 adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currency_name);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 OnItemSelectedListener listener = new CurrencySelectedListener();
 spin1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
 spin1.setAdapter(adapter);
 spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
 spin2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
 spin2.setAdapter(adapter);
 spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
 }


 private void calculateSum() {
 String [] rates = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.currency_rate);
 int index1 = spin1.getSelectedItemPosition();
 int index2 = spin2.getSelectedItemPosition();
 double rate1 = Double.parseDouble( rates[index1] );
 double rate2 = Double.parseDouble( rates[index2] );

 EditText editAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editAmount.getText().toString())) {
    double amount = Double.valueOf(editAmount.getText().toString());

    double totalRate = amount * rate1 / rate2;
     TextView totalRateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
     totalRateText.setText("" + totalRate);

    }




 }

 private class CurrencySelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
 calculateSum();
 }

 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
 }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `editAmount.getText().toString()` value is `NULL`(empty). And you still trying to convert this value into `DOUBLE` so you got `NumberFormatException` .

Check editText value before parsing like:

```
if(!editAmount.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
//Do your job
}
```

Or another way is

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editAmount.getText().toString())) {
//Do your job
}
```

Comment: `NULL` or `null` is something different than `""` :)

Comment: Im so sorry but dont really understand. Can you please elaborate

Comment: So ive done it like this:
`EditText editAmount;

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(editAmount.getText().toString())) {
double amount =Double.valueOf(editAmount.getText().toString());
  }`

Comment: I have updated the thread and also the code. Please check if you know how to solve this! Much apreciated!